# Missing wiki tag edits toward Research Assistant

Tags: bug, badges, editing, tags

I have made edits / contributions to a few tags and under the `Research Assistant` badge it shows that I have completed zero. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see that you have [three suggested (and accepted) tag wiki excerpt edits](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/38758/james-flattery?tab=activity&sort=suggestions) made, but no tag wikis. Does your score still say 0?

Probably it's because the excerpt isn't counted. If I look at [this tag](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/58321), the excerpt is filled out, but the tag wiki isn't.

[image]

Comment: @JamesFlattery You're welcome, and please continue with your good effort towards the research assistant badge. We need you :-)